# NetworkError: 404 Not Found in angularjs with ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting this error notification

> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
>   http://mylocal.com/assets/images/%7B%7B%20user.image%20%7D%7D"

I am using this code in view.

```
<img ng-if="user.image" src="assets/images/{{ user.image }}">
```

Although I have all images stored in server.

Please help me to understand that, why I am getting this error ? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular offers you `ng-src` - this way, the source url will be placed in `src` only after the interpolation has been made. This way you won't end up with the browser trying to get this url -

http://mylocal.com/assets/images/%7B%7B%20user.image%20%7D%7D"

Can you spot the **user.image** in the url? this indicates that the `src` has not been interpolated yet.

Comment: Your'e welcome, same thing in case your using `href` in anchor tags, use `ng-href` instead.

Comment: Thanks for this info ... :)

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using `src` instead of `ng-src`. change the `src` to `ng-src`